# What affects the pressue in an open vented central heating system

Tags: central-heating

Radiators in my loft do not work well, one proposed cause is insufficient pressure, other than the feed/cistern height what affects this ?

Although my radiators are in Loft the cistern in a roof void above the loft so I don't really see why my systems is any worse than if I had radiators on first floor, and then feed/cistern directly above on attic floor. Also since the house is effectively three stories with feed/cistern effectively on fourth storey it would seem the height and therefore pressure would actually be better than average.

I cannot move the tank any higher so what else affects the pressure ?

One thought I had is that air does seem to get into system could this be reducing the pressure, and where can the air be coming in from

I have already bled all radiators, circulating pump and magna clean system.

Answer (score 0):

Since the loft radiators were installed recently, my guess is that they are not piped correctly. If they are being fed off of another radiator supply, or the piping is too long or there is a restriction somewhere in the piping, these loft radiators may not be getting any water flow. You said in a previous post that when you bleed or vent the radiators that you get water from the vent. That said, the system must have enough pressure to hold a column of water up to the radiators. It may be time to call in an expert or better yet send tickets for round trip airfare for me or one of the other experts to your country. There is only so much we can recommend and since you don't seem to have enough heating system knowledge our recommendations aren't being put to good use. If you have water at the radiators, then the only other problem would be flow to those radiators. You may have to gain access to the piping to these radiators and take the required action to remedy the problem, ie; run new piping, install a bigger pump, whatever. Please call in an expert or send tickets.

Comment: *"Since the loft radiators were installed recently"* Where, exactly, did you come up with this? - The question does not state anything like that. Inventing conditions to answer does not benefit the actual question. The rest of your "answer" is merely inflammatory oboxiousness.

Comment: @d,george Actually all work was done by an 'expert' I haven't installed anything myself, however he is unsure how to proceed and is now away on vacation. So I thought it time to try and better understand the central heating system myself so I can then better understand the options. I ask these separate questions on the HomeImprovement site in the hope that the answers will help others and not be too specific to my situation, and it would be helpful if you actually tried to answer the specific question rather than just being rude.

Comment: To Mr. Ecnerwal; this is not my first answer. Rather than asking a stupid question, such as " where did you come up with this", read the previous posts between myself and Paul Taylor, before you rush to judgement. This post may not state anything like that but previous posts do mention that since different pipe (plastic) was used these rads are probably not as old as the original. And Paul Taylor said that they have never worked well. Please read before you judge. So NO , I did not invent a condition to answer. Read the original post "how do i force pump to force supply to radiators etc.

Comment: I did note the other answers after looking, however this did become a bit of a rant. Since there were 8 answers I think for same OP I could understand.